# Remove a widget generated with for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, tkinter, widget

I work on a python project, and I would like to create a history where each history is erasable with a "delete" button placed in the Frame of the widget

I tried to add the « delete » button in the loop where the widget was generated but it didn’t work as planned

```
history_files = os.listdir(history_directory)
history_files.sort(reverse=True)
number_of_h = 0
for file in history_files:
    file_dat = open(history_directory+"\\"+file)
    file_dat_lines = file_dat.readlines()
    action_amount_h = file_dat_lines[0]
    h_comment = file_dat_lines[1]
    h_date = file_dat_lines[2]
    h_time = file_dat_lines[3]
    history_f = Frame(history_win_f, bg=bg_theme, height=120, width=485, highlightbackground=bg_theme_2, highlightthickness=1)
    history_f.grid_propagate(False)
    history_f.columnconfigure(1, weight=70)
    history_f.columnconfigure(2, weight=30)
    history_f.rowconfigure(1, weight=60)
    history_f.rowconfigure(2, weight=40)
    action_h_f = LabelFrame(history_f, bg=bg_theme, width=390, height=120, font='Courrier 13 bold', labelanchor="n")
    action_h_f.grid_propagate(False)
    action_h_f.rowconfigure(1, weight=30)
    action_h_f.rowconfigure(2, weight=70)
    action_h_f.columnconfigure(1, weight=100)
    action_h_f.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")
    date_h_f = LabelFrame(history_f, bg=bg_theme, height=120, width=95, text=' Date ', labelanchor="n", font='Courrier 10 bold')
    date_h_f.grid(row=1, rowspan=2, column=2, sticky="nesw")
    date_h_f.rowconfigure(1, weight=50)
    date_h_f.rowconfigure(2, weight=50)
    date_h_f.columnconfigure(1, weight=100)
    date_l = Label(date_h_f, text="Le "+h_date, bg=bg_theme, fg=fg_theme_2, font='Courrier 8').grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nesw")
    time_l = Label(date_h_f, text="A "+h_time, bg=bg_theme, fg=fg_theme_2, font='Courrier 8').grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="nesw")
    date_h_f.grid_propagate(False)
    h_edit_a = Label(action_h_f, bg=bg_theme, font="Courrier 11", justify="center")
    h_edit_a_str = ""
```

I would appreciate any explanation, and if the code is simple, because I'm still a newbie. Thanks !

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what do you wish to accomplish. I can't see any button on your code and I'm not clear what do you wish to delete when the delete button is clicked.

As per my understanding, If the delete button is on the history_f, and you wish to remove or delete the Labels i.e. date_l and time_l then following is how you can do it.

```
for file in history_files:
    file_dat = open(history_directory+"\\"+file)
    file_dat_lines = file_dat.readlines()
    action_amount_h = file_dat_lines[0]
    h_comment = file_dat_lines[1]
    h_date = file_dat_lines[2]
    h_time = file_dat_lines[3]
    history_f = Frame(history_win_f, bg=bg_theme, height=120, width=485, highlightbackground=bg_theme_2, highlightthickness=1)
    history_f.grid_propagate(False)
    history_f.columnconfigure(1, weight=70)
    history_f.columnconfigure(2, weight=30)
    history_f.rowconfigure(1, weight=60)
    history_f.rowconfigure(2, weight=40)
    action_h_f = LabelFrame(history_f, bg=bg_theme, width=390, height=120, font='Courrier 13 bold', labelanchor="n")
    action_h_f.grid_propagate(False)
    action_h_f.rowconfigure(1, weight=30)
    action_h_f.rowconfigure(2, weight=70)
    action_h_f.columnconfigure(1, weight=100)
    action_h_f.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")
    date_h_f = LabelFrame(history_f, bg=bg_theme, height=120, width=95, text=' Date ', labelanchor="n", font='Courrier 10 bold')
    date_h_f.grid(row=1, rowspan=2, column=2, sticky="nesw")
    date_h_f.rowconfigure(1, weight=50)
    date_h_f.rowconfigure(2, weight=50)
    date_h_f.columnconfigure(1, weight=100)
    date_l = Label(date_h_f, text="Le "+h_date, bg=bg_theme, fg=fg_theme_2, font='Courrier 8').grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nesw")
    time_l = Label(date_h_f, text="A "+h_time, bg=bg_theme, fg=fg_theme_2, font='Courrier 8').grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="nesw")
    date_h_f.grid_propagate(False)
    h_edit_a = Label(action_h_f, bg=bg_theme, font="Courrier 11", justify="center")
    h_edit_a_str = ""

    ############################################
    #assume button is on action_h_f
    ttk.Button(action_h_f, text="delete", command=lambda : 
                           delete_record(date_l, time_l)

def delete_record(widget1, widget2):
    widget1.destroy()
    widget2.destroy()
```

you must pass the reference of both the label to the delete_record() function.

Just my guess, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes sorry about that, the widget I want to delete is a frame that contains the history of the actions I’ve made on that day, the software is a kind of money counter and the history gets whenever I took money, added or edited.

Comment: Also thanks for taking your time and try to help me on my problem. One thing I forgot to precise is that many labels are generated depending on how many actions I’ve made, and I’ve tried to pu the button in the frame but it deletes the lastly generated widget and when I try it on another one it tells me that the widget doesn’t exist, I think the widgets need tags when they’re generated so the destroy module finds the wanted widget, but I don’t know how to do It.

Answer (score 0):

Create the delete button inside `history_f` frame as well and destroy `history_f` when it is clicked.  Note that you do not call any layout function on `history_f`, so it will not be shown and you will get a blank window.

Below are the required changes:

```py
...
for file in history_files:
    ...
    history_f = Frame(history_win_f, bg=bg_theme, height=120, width=485, highlightbackground=bg_theme_2, highlightthickness=1)
    history_f.pack() # call layout function on history_f
    ...
    h_edit_a_str = ""

    # create delete button and destroy history_f when clicked
    Button(history_f, text="Delete", command=history_f.destroy).grid(row=1, column=4)
```

Comment: Okay, thanks ! I will try it as well as the other examples ! Thanks for taking your time.